# go build behaves strangely

Tags: go, build

I have following project structure

```
./
    lib/   shared library
    cmd/
        cli/
            main.go 
        srv/
            main.go
```

in the main.go i have

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println("cli")
}
```

from root folder i run `go build ./...`, in a hope that `cli` and `srv` binaries would be created in a root folder, but nothing happens

but running `go build ./cmd/cli` does produce a `cli` binary in root folder

what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of [Go 1.13](https://golang.org/doc/go1.13#go-command), `go build` will output multiple executables if you set the `-o` flag explicitly to a directory. So, for example, `mkdir -p ./bin && go build -o ./bin ./...` will build all executables matching `./...` and output them to the directory `./bin`.

Comment: Thanks, the `-o .` flag solved the problem